# Store.watch() events detail

Tags: flutter-objectbox

[Flutter/Dart]
What kind of information can I get from the Store.watch() stream?
Can I get entity type and entity id of insert/update/delete? Do I get a timestamp as well?

Thanks

-nat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Store.watch<EntityT>()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/objectbox/latest/objectbox/ObservableStore/watch.html) gives you changes for a given entity type (dart type). There's currently no way to get the exact object IDs for local changes - this is only present for changes received via ObjectBox Sync (on a [`SyncClient.changeEvents`](https://pub.dev/documentation/objectbox/latest/objectbox/SyncClient/changeEvents.html))